# Data pull using the 'with' statement in the query error

Tags: sql, teradata

I have written a query to pull some data and I have an error and I am new to using SQL when it comes to using multiple WITH statement, I have removed some of the columns for privacy reasons as displayed below however the error I am getting is shown below. Please give some suggestions. Thanks

```
Database: Terradata 
Query: SQL
```

ERROR:

```
SELECT Failed [ 3706] Syntax error: expected something between 'Study_Ongoing' and the 'AS' keyword
```

QUERY:

```
 WITH Study_Ongoing AS
(
SELECT
    Clnc_Actv_Id
    
FROM
P_Clnc_Actv_Lif_Cyc
where Actv_Ongo_Fl=1
),
Study_Ongoing_Group AS 
(
SELECT
    Clnc_Actv_Id as Actv_Id,
    Actv_Ongo_Fl
 
FROM
Study_Ongoing
GROUP BY
    Clnc_Actv_Id,
    Actv_Ongo_Fl,
    SO_Diff
)
Select 
    Actv_Id as "Protocol Id",
    
FROM
Study_Ongoing_Group
 inner join X_Calendar Cal
 on Cal.CAL_DT >= Vldt_Strt_Dttm and Cal.CAL_DT < Vldt_End_Dttm
 where CAL_DT >= Date '2019-01-01'


WITH Study_Ongoing AS              --> ERROR Points here
(
SELECT
    Clnc_Actv_Id,
    Ptcol_Sts_Ctms
FROM
P_Clnc_Actv_Lif_Cyc
where 
(Ptcol_Sts_Ctms ='Open' or Ptcol_Sts_Ctms='Execution' or Fst_Site_Open_Actl is not null or Fst_Subj_Scrnd_Actl is not null or Fst_Subj_Enrld_Actl is not null)
and
Last_Subj_Last_Visit_Extd_Actl is null
and
Last_Site_Clse_Actl is null
and
Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Not Selected' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Not Required' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Completed' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Closed' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Cancelled' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Stopped' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Terminated'
),
Study_Ongoing_Group AS 
(
SELECT
    Clnc_Actv_Id as Actv_Id,
    Ptcol_Sts_Ctms
    
FROM
Study_Ongoing
GROUP BY
    Clnc_Actv_Id,
    Ptcol_Sts_Ctms
  
)
Select 
    Actv_Id as "Protocol Id",
    Ptcol_Sts_Ctms
  
FROM
Study_Ongoing_Group
 inner join X_Calendar Cal
 on Cal.CAL_DT >= Vldt_Strt_Dttm and Cal.CAL_DT < Vldt_End_Dttm
 where CAL_DT >= Date '2019-01-01')
```

Comment: Statements must be separated by semicolons.

Comment: Those GROUP BY's look strange.

Comment: @dnoeth Do you mean with the statement above should have a semicolon?

Comment: To clarify dnoeth's point, you have two completely separate queries.  You need a semicolon between the first and second queries. The second query starts on the line you indicate gets the error.  If you aren't intending to have two separate queries, then you're going to need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

WITH Study_Ongoing AS
(
SELECT
Clnc_Actv_Id

```
FROM
P_Clnc_Actv_Lif_Cyc
where Actv_Ongo_Fl=1
),
Study_Ongoing_Group AS 
(
SELECT
    Clnc_Actv_Id as Actv_Id,
    Actv_Ongo_Fl
 
FROM
Study_Ongoing
GROUP BY
    Clnc_Actv_Id,
    Actv_Ongo_Fl,
    SO_Diff
)
Select 
    Actv_Id as "Protocol Id",
    
FROM
Study_Ongoing_Group
 inner join X_Calendar Cal
 on Cal.CAL_DT >= Vldt_Strt_Dttm and Cal.CAL_DT < Vldt_End_Dttm
 where CAL_DT >= Date '2019-01-01';   --> fixed with semicolon


WITH Study_Ongoing AS              --> ERROR Points here
(
SELECT
    Clnc_Actv_Id,
    Ptcol_Sts_Ctms
FROM
P_Clnc_Actv_Lif_Cyc
where 
(Ptcol_Sts_Ctms ='Open' or Ptcol_Sts_Ctms='Execution' or Fst_Site_Open_Actl is not null or Fst_Subj_Scrnd_Actl is not null or Fst_Subj_Enrld_Actl is not null)
and
Last_Subj_Last_Visit_Extd_Actl is null
and
Last_Site_Clse_Actl is null
and
Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Not Selected' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Not Required' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Completed' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Closed' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Cancelled' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Stopped' and Ptcol_Sts_Ctms<>'Terminated'
),
Study_Ongoing_Group AS 
(
SELECT
    Clnc_Actv_Id as Actv_Id,
    Ptcol_Sts_Ctms
    
FROM
Study_Ongoing
GROUP BY
    Clnc_Actv_Id,
    Ptcol_Sts_Ctms
  
)
Select 
    Actv_Id as "Protocol Id",
    Ptcol_Sts_Ctms
  
FROM
Study_Ongoing_Group
 inner join X_Calendar Cal
 on Cal.CAL_DT >= Vldt_Strt_Dttm and Cal.CAL_DT < Vldt_End_Dttm
 where CAL_DT >= Date '2019-01-01')
```